# How do I embed data into jQuery template attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I have the following jQuery-tmpl template:

```
<script id="month-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div style="width:${width};">
        <div>Hello</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

It is used by the following script:

```
$("#month-template").tmpl({"width":30}).appendTo($("#containerId"));
```

I expect to see this output:

```
<div style="width:30;">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

But I get this:

```
<div style="">
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Is there some special way to embed attribute values in a template?
I am new to tmpl - maybe I have missed something obvious.

Comment: Can you try "width":"30px" just to be sure?

Comment: \*facepalm\* @waitinforatrain That worked. Post an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `30px` instead of `30`.

jQuery automatically converts integers to the correct CSS units when using `.css()` but since it's a template (not CSS-specific) you need to specify the units yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was so convinced it was an issue with tmpl, I missed a very basic thing.